# How to tell syslog-ng to ignore source files if they are absent

Tags: linux, syslog, syslog-ng

I'm trying to deploy a standard configuration file for syslog-ng on multiple linux servers. My infrastructure includes many services (apache, confluence, ...) with log file located at various places.

See the excerpt of my custom syslog-ng config file :

```
source s_auditd {
  file("/var/log/audit/audit.log" flags(no-parse) program-override("auditd"));
};

source s_app {
  file("/opt/atlassian/confluence/logs/catalina.out" flags(no-parse) program-override("confluence"));
  file("/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/catalina.out" flags(no-parse) program-override("jira"));
};
```

My config file could be deployed on servers that are not hosting confluence for example. But syslog-ng will try to look for log file I declared into my source s_app anyway and going to throw errors.

My question is simple : is there a mechanism where I can tell syslog-ng to ignore absent log file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO you're approaching this the wrong way around.

Rather than monolithic configuration that must include everything, go for a minimal universal config, that leverages the dynamic loading of external configuration files/snippets from a drop-in directory:

[`@include "/path/to/syslog-ng.conf.d/"`](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.19/administration-guide/15#TOPIC-1094514)

That minimal config can be deployed everywhere and will always work, while you add system/role specific syslog-ng configuration sections as drop-in files, one for each role/service that gets installed on that particular server. That is something which is easily managed by whatever deployment and/or configuration management solution that is employed at your site and also the approach that most distributions are taking for a plethora of tools.

When you deploy for example Confluence, also deploy a `/path/to/syslog-ng.conf.d/confluence.conf` with the specific additional configuration that is required to monitor Confluence on that host.

Comment: Yes, this is the idea I came up at first. But to me it adds a bit of complexity when shared things exist between the files. For example, if my server destination change it would be painstaking to modify the setting inside all my config files. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the [wildcard-file source](https://axoflow.com/docs/axosyslog-core/chapter-sources/configuring-sources-wildcard-file/), AFAIK that doesn't throw errors if it doesn't match any file.

(the link points to the documentation of Axosyslog, which is a cloud-ready syslog-ng distribution maintained by the original creator of syslog-ng)